# Disable IP and Transport layer checksum on Linux

Tags: linux, udp, ip, kernel, checksum

I'd like to ask whether its possible to disable checksum in the Linux network stack.
Is it possible to indicate that my network driver is doing the checksums and they're not required to be done by the NS?

Assume I'm willing to modify the kernel or at least rebuild it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you willing to write a Kernel module or asking about a user-space method to do this (via /proc for example) ?

Comment: Are you creating only UDP/TCP packets or IP packets as well? How do you know the checksum is being recalculated by the networks stack?

Comment: This is an old question, but in case people are still reading it, do not disable UDP checksums for DNS nameservers.  Eventually there will be a packet corruption and the DNS server may cache that corrupted answer for a significant period of time. Finding this service failure can be extremely difficult. Back in the 1990s we spent substantial time following up system administrators to enable UDP on all nameservers so that DNS would be reliable. Let's not go back there.